# Unity. Animation not playing when I press button (SetTrigger)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I'm trying to make this 2D character play an attack animation when I do left click, I know I cannot do that with just Animator.Play because its only playing for the frame which Input.GetMouseButton(0) is true, right?

So I checked online and I saw that I had to use a trigger parameter instead, because its true then after the animation is done, its not true, so it would work.

This is the code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            anims.SetTrigger("Attacking");
        }
```

And this is the animator:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/786rs.png)

As you can see all seems to be set correctly and then here you can see compiling the game, it even triggers true when I click the mouse, but the transition from idle to attack doesn't happen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1cgg.png)

What could be wrong here?

Thank you for your time and help!

I checked online and I saw that I had to use a trigger parameter instead, because its true then after the animation is done, its not true, so it would work.

Comment: what does your transition from attack back to idle look like? Maybe it is triggered immediately as well?

Comment: Hi! At the end I solved the problem, I don't know exactly why it happened but I was calling the other animations with the method anims.Play() while a condition was met, so it wasn't triggered only once, whatever, at the end I just made them all work through triggers instead, and it worked.